# TF tree not showing the frames that i need

Tags: rviz

I am using melodic 18.04 and rviz,
and am doing amcl on rviz but my robot model has everything but the 4 wheels
Error shows `[no transform from [all 4 wheels_links] to [base_footprint]`
The other sensors and urdf are all working fine
how do i fix this?

This is my current launch file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>

    <arg name="robot_namespace" default="/"/>

    <!-- Load URDF model -->
    <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find limo_description)/urdf/limo_ackerman.xacro'
        robot_namespace:=$(arg robot_namespace)" />

    <!-- Load joint controller configurations from YAML file to parameter server -->
    <rosparam file="$(find limo_gazebo_sim)/config/limo_ackerman_control.yaml" command="load"/>

    <!-- Load controllers -->
    <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen"
          args="limo_state_controller limo_fl_steering_hinge_controller limo_fr_steering_hinge_controller"/>

    <!-- Robot state publisher for URDF visualization -->
    <node name="robot_state_publisher" pkg="robot_state_publisher" type="robot_state_publisher" />

    <!-- Use robot pose ekf to provide odometry -->
    <node pkg="robot_pose_ekf" name="robot_pose_ekf" type="robot_pose_ekf">
        <param name="output_frame" value="odom" />
        <param name="base_footprint_frame" value="base_link" />
        <remap from="imu_data" to="imu" />
    </node>

    <!-- Launch AMCL for localization -->
    <node pkg="amcl" type="amcl" name="amcl" output="screen">
        <rosparam file="$(find limo_bringup)/param/amcl_params_omni.yaml" command="load" />
    <param name="initial_pose_x" value="0" />
    <param name="initial_pose_y" value="0" />
    <param name="initial_pose_a" value="0" />
    <param name="global_frame_id" value="map" />
    <param name="map_file" value="$(find limo_bringup)/maps/mylimomap.yaml" />
    </node>

    <!-- Launch RViz with the amcl.rviz configuration -->
    <node name="rviz_amcl" pkg="rviz" type="rviz" args="-d $(find limo_bringup)/rviz/amcl.rviz" />

</launch>
```

This is the link for my view frames tree:
[image]

This is how it looks like in my rviz(the error):
[image]

please help me and let me know if you need more files thankyou

Comment: It looks like you are missing a `joint_state_publisher` (https://wiki.ros.org/joint_state_publisher), it would either publish wheel rotations of zero for the wheels or take in rotation values from another node, and then robot_state_publisher would publish the transforms to attach them to the vehicle

Comment: @LucasWalter oh wow thankyou for the help and the edits to make it so much neater, appreciate it , i will try if the joint state publisher works , thankyou!